# WPF host silverlight with simple custom web sever on client

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I have a requirement to host Silverlight in WPF app.
I am able to do it fine using a WebBrowser. But the silverlight is unable to show images from internet due to perms issue. So we signed the xap using Clickonce cert but still the same issue.

When the xap is hosted onto a server then silverlight app show images from other domain fine without any errors.

So want a solution to run a small webserver when WPF app is launched and serve the xap file from that.

Note: cannot host on an external server as we want to open the app offline too.

Comment: silver light is going to be dead in 3 years...probably should use something else instead

Comment: Use HTML5 instead or native WPF. Silverlight is dead

Comment: Ya i know that but we are playing smoothstreaming videos. So silverlight is only option.